# What is the practical use of "Type-only Field Declarations"?

Tags: typescript

Source: [Type-only Field Declarations](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#type-only-field-declarations).

```
interface Animal {
  dateOfBirth: any;
}
 
interface Dog extends Animal {
  breed: any;
}
 
class AnimalHouse {
  resident: Animal;
  constructor(animal: Animal) {
    this.resident = animal;
  }
}
 
class DogHouse extends AnimalHouse {
  // Does not emit JavaScript code,
  // only ensures the types are correct
  declare resident: Dog;
  constructor(dog: Dog) {
    super(dog);
  }
}
```

I think I can understand the official example, but I don't know where it should be used! Are there any real examples?

Comment: What would make an example "real"? You want someone to find an existing public code base that uses it?

Comment: @jcalz What I need are examples used in real projects(a mini example that can explain its purpose clearly)!

Comment: Can someone explain what this thing is for?

Comment: It's a refinement. In a doghouse, the residents are dogs, not just any animals. But to make that refinement, we don't need to declare a new *field*, we just need to change the existing one. Does that make sense?

Comment: It's for narrowing the type of a superclass's property in a subclass, without emitting any JavaScript code (which could do undesirable things like initialize the property in the subclass to `undefined`).  Explaining with new made-up examples is easy, but finding a "real" project that uses it and explaining *that* is more effort than I can imagine spending here.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Yeah, I understand this, I'm just a little confused about what it can do.

Comment: Like [here is a different made-up example](https://tsplay.dev/wOLXEN) where a `Tree` holds arbitrary data but a `StringTree` only holds strings; the subclass doesn't have anything extra at runtime; it's just TS narrowing types for its properties.  If you actually *do* emit field declarations at runtime, bad things happen.  I'd be happy to write this up as an answer if it helps, but... it's probably not "real".

Comment: @jcalz Cool, this is the answer I want, that is, it can narrow the type of superclass property, and this mini example can already be used in real projects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a [`declare` modifier on a class field](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) if you don't want to emit a [public class field](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields) for that property to JavaScript.  TypeScript added class field declarations before JavaScript did, and TypeScript's implementation behaved a little differently.  In JavaScript, if you declare a field but do not actively initialize it, it will be initialized to `undefined`, *even in subclasses where the property might have been set by the call to `super()`*.  That's different from how TypeScript did things, and so TypeScript had to adapt to it: if you want to just inherit a property from a superclass but narrow its type, you should use `declare`.

---

For example, imagine a base `Tree` class which holds a `value` of [the `unknown` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#unknown) and a `children` array of `Tree`s:

```
// TS input
class Tree {
    value: unknown;
    children: Tree[] = [];
    constructor(value: unknown) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Depending on your [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/target.html) and TS config settings, this will be emitted as-is with just the types removed:

```
// JS output
class Tree {
    value;
    children = [];
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Now we'd like to create a `StringTree` subclass which does the same thing as `Tree` but the `value` property is limited to `string`s and the `children` property is limited to an array of `StringTree` elements.  Before JavaScript introduced class fields, the "right" way to do this in TypeScript was to just re-declare the fields and maybe use a [definite assignment assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) so the compiler doesn't complain about initialization:

```
// TS input
class StringTree extends Tree {
    value!: string; 
    children!: StringTree[];
    constructor(value: string) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

But this can now be emitted as follows:

```
// JS output
class StringTree extends Tree {
    value;
    children;
    constructor(value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

which doesn't do what you wanted:

```
const b = new StringTree("hello");
console.log(b.value.toUpperCase()) // RUNTIME ERROR, b.value is undefined
```

The `value` and `children` properties in the subclass are initialized to `undefined` after the call to `super()`.  Oops.  And in fact the above subclass declaration gives errors on those subclass fields saying this, and what to do about it:

```
Property 'value' will overwrite the base property in 'Tree'. 
If this is intentional, add an initializer. Otherwise, add a 
'declare' modifier or remove the redundant declaration.
```

This is where `declare` comes in.  You can use `declare` instead of the definite assignment assertion.  This will suppress all JS output for the subclass property while still narrowing its TypeScript type:

```
// TS input
class StringTree extends Tree {
    declare value: string;
    declare children: StringTree[];
    constructor(value: string) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

Now the output is

```
// JS output
class StringTree extends Tree {
    constructor(value) {
        super(value);
    }
}
```

and everything works as desired:

```
const a = new StringTree("hello");
console.log(a.value.toUpperCase()) // "HELLO"
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?useDefineForClassFields=true&target=99#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqBOBTR0DeAoaXoDcwgFdEAuaAgOwGtyB7Ad3IG5NtgALASxABMlzSEyANoBdaAF5oo5tmjAa5CABd4BYEprwAFHkIkyVWgwCUaFrKxLOEAHS6iE3PiIzsAX3Qf0Aem-QA5jQ03NDooJAwAMoqHOT+giiIAB5KiOTcMAlmstyI4UhOeqTK8LH+rli5+SjsXLxppNGlcQnS5nIKJWoa2vb6JWWmGBbYEAQADoi9zojGFdAeXvKKStBgjuSIdNBNZQlaAERsiCAgNAdzYZ00IIg2Z-5aYHYzNhoAquOT8ADCkIhaYymXzQA4ACQAogAZKEAeQO6B8fgARmBuGFwFBoAAhNG7FpIRIpNIZOCE7LYPoAQmKMTi81qPD4NJxeLp8UJbVkyy66k0OhmtOa-iG7VkY2+Ar0l1kiyuK2gyI2W1Z3HxHOQh2Op3Olx5NzuDy0yJeejeNE+3z+EABQOgIIASu8AHKwACSAFkIdAIQ6HbCHQAaRWmhwcGAUXIAM1iiG4QA)